# Ruby on rails if condition when adding new data to a sql table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, boolean

I'm pretty new to ruby & ruby on rails and I have a little question :
I want to set a boolean to true if the value of the entry is higher than X and another boolean to true if this value if lower than Y.

I don't really know where to do the code for this or what's the best way to do it.

To be clear, I have a form(made with a scaffold) where I ask a value and depending on this value one of the 2 boolean might be set to true.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put this on your controller. I would assume that the form is on `controller#create` where you would have:

```
boolean = true if @model.value > x
boolean2 = true if @model.value < y
```

then save it on db with `@model.save`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those booleans are attributes of the same model you have `value` on, it seems you could do this in `before_save` callback:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Your X & Y with some example values
  X_VALUE = 5
  Y_VALUE = 10

  before_save do
    self.boolean1 = self.value > X_VALUE
    self.boolean2 = self.value < Y_VALUE
    true # callback needs to return true, otherwise save will fail
  end
end
```

With above implementation even if you update the value, the proper boolean values will change as well. I hope this helps, as it's made on some assumptions. If not let me know, we'll figure something out.